# View restriction at a page level

Tags: 2007

I want to create a page with a special view of one list, but I want that only one user can access this page. Is it possible? MOSS 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a page in a Page Library and affect the good security to this item.  It would do the trick.  On the other side, your list view can't have security elements, so, if a user gets to the list, he will be able to view the list and the views.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create 2 pages. Each page with Web Part that shows a different view of the list. I want that all users can access one of the 2 pages, but only one can access the page that displays the restricted one.

Comment: What Sebastien is saying is that you can't secure the target list, so whether the page is accessible or not, the data is not secure.

Comment: Yes, my client doesn't care. They just one one link(first page) to appear to everybody, and another link(second page) that only appears to one user.

Comment: I also typed the name of the user that can see the link in the audience field of the global navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Since the page has to be stored in a library, you can simply break permissions on this single page and give permissions only to one user.